# Map conditional child elements

Tags: json, jq

I am working with a JSON file which has contains lot of data that can be removed before sending to an API.

Found that JQ can be used to achieve this but not sure on how to map to get the desired results.

**Input JSON**

```
  {
    "name": "Sample name",
    "id": "123",
    "userStory": {
      "id": "234",
      "storyName": "Story Name",
      "narrative": "Narrative",
      "type": "feature"
    },
    "testSteps": [
      {
        "number": 1,
        "description": "Step 1",
        "level": 0,
        "children": [
          {
            "number": 2,
            "description": "Description",
            "children": [
              {
                "number": 3,
                "description": "Description"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "number": 4,
            "anotherfield": "another field"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

***Desired Output***

```
{
  "name": "Sample name",
  "userStory": {
    "storyName": "Story Name"
  },
  "testSteps": [
    {
      "description": "Step 1",
      "children": [
        {
          "description": "Description",
          "children": [
            {
              "description": "Description"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "anotherfield": "anotherfield"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Tried to do it with the following jq command

`map_values(..|{name, id, userStory})`

but not sure how to filter only the userStory.storyName.

Thanks in advance.

***Note:*** The actual JSON has different child elements that are repeated in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete `.id` from root object:

```
del(.id)
```

To leave only `.storyName` in `.userStory`:

```
.userStory |= {storyName}
```

To delete `.number` and `.level` from every object on any level in `.testSteps`:

```
.testSteps |= walk(if type == "object" then del(.number, .level) else . end)
```

Putting it all together:

```
del(.id) | (.userStory |= {storyName}) | (.testSteps |=
  walk(if type == "object" then del(.number, .level) else . end))
```

[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/n8B2lgTafY)